# LINQ Comparison error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting a comparison error message when trying to update a record using LINQ.

```
var tools = from tl in MVCWebsite.MvcApplication.DataContext.tblTools
                                               where tl.pk_fk_Environment == model.Environment
                                               && tl.pk_fk_Classification == model.Classification
                                               && tl.pk_ToolNumber == model.ToolNumber
                                               select tl;
        Models.Database.tblTool updatingTool = tools.First();
        //try
        //{

        if (createPerson(model.ToolEngineer, true) != null)
            updatingTool.fk_Engineer = model.ToolEngineer;
        else
            updatingTool.fk_Engineer = null;

        updatingTool.fk_BuiltBy = model.ToolBuiltBy;

        if (createPerson(model.ToolBuiltBy, true) != null)
            updatingTool.fk_BuiltBy = model.ToolBuiltBy;
        else
            updatingTool.fk_BuiltBy = null;
        if (createPerson(model.ToolDesignedBy, true) != null)
            updatingTool.fk_Designer = model.ToolDesignedBy;
        else
            updatingTool.fk_Designer = null;
        updatingTool.DateOfBuild = model.DateOfBuild;
        updatingTool.Machine_Name_Primary = model.ToolPrimaryMachineName;
        updatingTool.Machine_Description_Primary = model.ToolPrimaryMachineDescription;
        updatingTool.Machine_Name_Secondary = model.ToolSecondaryMachineName;
        updatingTool.Machine_Description_Secondary = model.ToolSecondaryMachineDescription;
        updatingTool.MERNumber = model.MERNumber;
        updatingTool.AssetNumber = model.AssetNumber;
        updatingTool.Additional_Cavities = model.AdditionalFields.Cavities;
        updatingTool.Additional_Gate = model.AdditionalFields.TypeOfGate;
        updatingTool.Additional_Shrinkage = model.AdditionalFields.Shrinkage;
        updatingTool.Additional_DieClearance = model.AdditionalFields.DieClearance;
        updatingTool.Additional_Field1 = model.AdditionalFields.Additional1;
        updatingTool.Additional_Field2 = model.AdditionalFields.Additional2;
        updatingTool.Additional_Field3 = model.AdditionalFields.Additional3;
        updatingTool.Additional_Field4 = model.AdditionalFields.Additional4;
        updatingTool.Additional_OtherInformation = model.AdditionalFields.OtherInformation;
```

(Below is the create user function)

```
private Models.Database.tblPerson createPerson(string user)
    {
        if (user == null || user == "")
            return null;
        var people = from p in MVCWebsite.MvcApplication.DataContext.tblPersons
                     where p.pk_PersonID == user
                     select p;
        if (people.Count() == 1)
        {
            return people.First();
        }
        else
        {
            Models.UserInformation ui;
            ui = MVCWebsite.MvcApplication.DisplayUser(user);
            if (!ui.Exists)
                return null;
            tblPerson person = new tblPerson()
            {
                pk_PersonID = user,
                FirstName = ui.GivenName,
                LastName = ui.Surname,
                Email = ui.EmailAddress
            };
            return person;
        }
    }
```

I am not bothered about if my code is clean or not at the moment, I am just getting this error and it is starting to annoy me.

Here is the Main Table Scripted as a Create (So you can see the field settings:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTool](
    [pk_fk_Environment] [varchar](2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [pk_fk_Classification] [varchar](3) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [pk_fk_Style] [varchar](4) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [pk_ToolNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBuild] [datetime] NULL,
    [fk_Engineer] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_Designer] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_BuiltBy] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [MERNumber] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [AssetNumber] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_Material] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_LocationCompany] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_LocationCountry] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_LocationRegion] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [fk_Status] [varchar](10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Machine_Name_Primary] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Machine_Description_Primary] [text] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Machine_Name_Secondary] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Machine_Description_Secondary] [text] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [OldToolID] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Cavities] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Gate] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Shrinkage] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_DieClearance] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Field1] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Field2] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Field3] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_Field4] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Additional_OtherInformation] [text] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTool] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_fk_Environment] ASC,
    [pk_fk_Classification] ASC,
    [pk_ToolNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

When updating the field with the same information that is already in it I get the Error:

```
SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.
```

Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: `I am not bothered about if my code is clean or not at the moment` But you expect us to read it

Comment: It is your choice if you want to help me or not. My code generally starts off messy and at the end of that sections development gets cleaned to look clean and preform better as well.

All I mean't by that is I didn't want people wasting their time cleaning my code for me.

Besides, my code might be a bit long winded, however it is not "that" messy.

At the end of the day, don't bother posting something which isn't contributory. I have had to read code much more untidy than this before.

Comment: @OliverBaker: Your code was just fine.  I could figure out everything I needed to just by looking at it for under a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Additional_OtherInformation`, `Machine_Description_Primary`, and `Machine_Description_Secondary`  columns from the deprecated `TEXT` datatype to the `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype.  Refresh your column mappings, and you should be all set.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening? Am I comparing it somewhere and just bind enough that I've missed it?

Comment: Hard to say.  It could likely be that L2S wants to perform some sort of equality check to see if the value has been changed (part of the optimistic concurrency stuff).  Either way, you should go ahead and replace every single reference to TEXT, NTEXT, or IMAGE in your database to VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(MAX), and VARBINARY(MAX), respecively, which are the supported datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am still pretty new to SQL Types, and since I wasn't comparing these fields I didn't think it would have been an issue. Oh well, Thanks!